# Make text in header responsive on all screens

Tags: css, responsive-design

how do I make the 'name' text align to the center for different screen resolutions? I think the culprit is I hid the TikTok logo on smaller screens. Thanks in advance for your help!

HTML:

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2 class="name">Name</h2>
  <a
    class="social-icon-header"
    href="https://www.tiktok.com/@xxx"
    target="_blank"
  >
    <i class="fab fa-tiktok fa-2x"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
/* Header */

.social-icon-header {
  display: none;
}

.name {
  text-align: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  /* padding-left: 15%; */
}[![screenshots][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and don't forget to set the `height`(in this case `min-height:100vh`) property. If you want to center also vertically.If not you can remove it. And if you want to make strictly responsive text, use [this resource](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

```css
/* Header */

.social-icon-header {
  display: none;
 
}

.name {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2 class="name">Name</h2>
  <a class="social-icon-header" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@tretuser" target="_blank">
    <i class="fab fa-tiktok fa-2x"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @MarioG8, thanks for the answer. I tried it but it didn't move the Name at all. I didn't include "min-height" as I didn't want to center it vertically. Any other ways to center it? Thanks!